# Custom selectbox trigger onchange event multiple times

Tags: jquery, magento, prototype

We have implemented a [jQuery selectbox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) and created a custom trigger event to get the data when a selectbox is changed. For example, we use this to select the desired product attribute options in a Magento shop.

Everything goes well until we select an option which has already triggered in the same 'session'. Then nothing happens. How is that possible?

**The trigger event:**

```
Element.prototype.triggerEvent = function(eventName)
{
    if (document.createEvent)
    {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent(eventName, true, true);

        return this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    if (this.fireEvent)
        return this.fireEvent('on' + eventName);
}

var global_select = '';

function customEvent(id, event) {
    global_select = id;
    $(id).triggerEvent(event);
    global_select = '';
}
```

**The jQuery code:**

```
jQuery('select').change(function(e) { 
    id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    if (id && id != global_select)
        customEvent(jQuery(this).attr('id'), 'change');

    jQuery('select').each(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        if (jQuery(this).css('display') == 'none') {
            jQuery(this).selectbox('detach');
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).selectbox('attach');
        }
    });
});

jQuery('select').each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).css('display') != 'none') {
        jQuery(this).selectbox();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by changing the jQuery version from 1.10.2 to 1.8.2.